# New SQLContext: Spark 1.6 backward-compatibility with Spark 2.1

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, data-science-experience

On IBM DSX I have the following problem.

For the Spark 1.6 kernels on DSX it was/is necessary to create new SQLContext objects in order to avoid issues with the `metastore_db` and `HiveContext` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38117849/you-must-build-spark-with-hive-export-spark-hive-true/38118112#38118112

The following code snippets were implemented using Spark 1.6 and both run for Spark 2.0.2, but not for Spark 2.1:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c"), (4, "d")], ("k", "v"))
df.count()
```

and

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

properties= {
    'jdbcurl': 'JDBCURL',
    'user': 'USER',
    'password': 'PASSWORD!'
}

data_df_1 = sqlContext.read.jdbc(properties['jdbcurl'], table='GOSALES.BRANCH', properties=properties)
data_df_1.head()
```

I get this error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: u"Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':"
```

However, when I execute the same code a second time it works again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a new SQLContext using SQLContext(sc) you can use SQLContext.getOrCreate(sc). This will return an existing SQLContext if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, creating a new `SQLContext` was only necessary for the legacy Spark services (bluemix_ipythonspark_16) in Bluemix. DSX supports only the newer services (bluemix_jupyter_bundle), where creating a new `SQLContext` is more likely to create problems with Hive than to solve them. Please try without.